# Common structures in Gurobi - Python

Tags: linear-programming, constraint, python, gurobi, logical-constraints

I'm new to Gurobi in Python and I was wondering if someone knows how to code some common structures of linear constraints. I'm trying to understand how you'll code something like the following constraints: \begin{alignat}2\sum_{i\in A\mid i\ne j}\sum_{j\in A\mid i\ne j}x_{ij}&\le10\tag1\\\sum_{i\in A\mid i\ne j}x_{ij}&\le10\quad\forall j\in B\tag2\\x_{ij}&\le10\quad\forall i\in A,j\in B\mid i\ne j\tag3.\end{alignat}

In FICO Xpress, the first constraint would be coded like:

```
sum(i in A, j in A | i<>j)x(i,j)<=10
```

But I don't know how to code such structures in Gurobi Python.

If you can provide a code example, that would be great.

Comment: Did you take a look at the examples in the gurobi documentation https://www.gurobi.com/resource/functional-code-examples/ and https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/? If you are familiar with XPRESS, see here https://www.gurobi.com/resource/switching-from-xpress/

Comment: You may find the following thread useful: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/797/how-to-model-a-mixed-integer-linear-programming-formulation-in-python-using-guro/798#798

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Python syntax could be like this:

1. `model.addConstr(sum(x[i,j] for i in A for j in A if i != j) <= 10,  "firstConstraint")`
2. `model.addConstrs(sum(x[i,j] for i in A if i != j) <= 10 for j in B,  "secondConstraintClass")`
3. `model.addConstr(x[i,j] <= 10 for i in A for j in B if i != j,  "thirdConstraintClass")`

where `model` is the gurobi API object in your code.

Note that `addConstrs` is for the case when you add many similar constraints indexed by a set, while `addConstr` is for when you add only one constraint at the time (note the `for j in B` after the inequality and  before the comma in the second constraint where `addConstrs` is used).

You can check more about the `addConstrs` method in its [documentation](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/refman/py_model_addconstrs.html), including some examples and use cases.

For sums over large arrays or linear products, or when adding a linear product where the coefficients could be sparse, I'd recommend reading about the [quicksum](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/refman/py_quicksum.html) and [LinExpr](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/refman/py_linexpr2.html) methods which can yield further efficiency.

Answer (score 5):

*Let's define the model as **m**:*

`m = Model('AnyName')`

*Now the constraint can be added to the model:*

`m.addConstrs((xVar.sum('*',i) <= 10 for i in A, j in B, i<>j), "constraintName")`

Source: https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/quickstart_mac/py_netflow_py_example.html

Comment: Thanks, for your answer! I'll assume that the sum("*",i,j) part is the translation of Xpress' sum(i in A, j in A | i<>j), making that i<>j is the same as ("*",i,j). Am I right?

Comment: @SantiagoAm16 I edited the code, hopefully it covers all the details now.

Comment: I don't think `i<>j` is valid Python syntax and could not find that part in the provided source. Should it be `i != j` instead?

Comment: @RobertSchwarz i was thinking the exact same, however, I think another form to write it would be with an if statement after the for  statement in the sum. I’ll try both forms today and let you know.

Comment: Just tried to model one constraint in the above format, but apparently it doesn't work. I did it in this format: `for i in range(NumOfJobs):
    m.addConstr(quicksum(z[j,i] for j in range(NumOfJobs)) == 1)` And it works, but if I write: `for i in range(NumOfJobs):
    m.addConstr(z.sum(j,'*') == 1 for j in range(NumOfJobs))` it doesn't works. I think both should equal the same.