# How to write this constraint in Gurobi python?

Tags: gurobi

I'm wondering how I can translate this math constraint to gurobi python.

$$\forall a \in A, b \in B, x_{ab} \in \{0, 1\}$$

So far I have written:

```
xab = m.addVar(lb=0, ub=1, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="xab")
```

But I'm not sure what to add for the constraints section...

```
m.addConstr(?? for a in A for b in B, "c0")
```

Is it really as simple as replacing ?? with `xab`?

Comment: Implementing a complete problem is elaborated here: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/797/how-to-model-a-mixed-integer-linear-programming-formulation-in-python-using-guro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from gurobipy import *
A = []; B = [] # You need to enter the data in these lists 

m = Model()
x = {} # Dictionary of variables
for a in A:
    for b in B:
        x[a, b] = m.addVar(lb=0, ub=1, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="x_" +str(a) + str(b))
```

Note: Adding binary variables would constrain them to take values either 0 or 1. To add constraints involving these variables, you can use the following example syntax:

```
m.addConstr(x[a1, b1] + x[a2, b2] <= 10, name = 'c0')
```

Comment: This is a good starting point but it seems that the OP question was mainly about how to add *constraints* to a Gurobi model.

Comment: I'm confused. Does this edit address the issue?

Comment: Thank you very much for improving your answer. I think it is more informative now. Even better would be to show how to set a constraint with the number of operands depending on the problem's input data.

Answer (score 2):

```
x = m.addVars(A, B, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="x")
```

then `x` becomes a dict whose key is a tuple `(a,b)`, and the value is a Var.

To add a set of constraints

```
m.addConstrs(x[a,b]+y[a,b]<=c[a,b] for a in A for b in B)
```